# Upgrading to WP10 Tech Preview from 8.1, is my SD card safe?

Tags: 8.1, insider-preview, storage

I am strongly considering upgrading my Windows Phone 8.1 to the Windows Phone 10 Tech Preview to test some new features, but I'm trying to do some research on the risks associated with doing so before I actually decide to go through with upgrading. By upgrading, as I understand, all data stored in the phone will be erased. Will I need to worry about my SD card being erased?

Comment: I would remove the SD card during the upgrade and/or downgrade. That's just a personal preference

Comment: Upgrading will never erase sd, so just dont worry and do it!

Answer (score 1):

All your data *should* be kept intact through the upgrade, though it wouldn't be a bad idea to create a backup first. If you are really worried, your best bet would be to remove your SD card while upgrading.

Comment: **Some** apps won't work normally.

Answer (score -2):

No, your SD card and phone data will be not erased. But your phone will hang a lot. There are too many bugs in W10 TP.

Comment: You can't really say the phone will hang a lot without knowing what phone it is. My 635 runs W10 just fine.